# CSS Skill Bar Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, responsive

So I am just finally getting some content creation stuff into my first responsive website for mobile and desktop and I would like to know how you can make a skill bar much more readable in mobile. I got what I like in desktop version, but now in mobile I want the bars to fill the screen from left to right and make the text still readable on small devices.

Here is where I got the code from. They don't have any information on how to make this skill bar responsive. So that is my goal here. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_skill_bar)

This is what my desktop version looks like now currently

[image]

But when I go into Dev mode to view it in iPhone format, this is what it looks like

[image]

This is what I was trying to attempt:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .skillResponsive {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: justify;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 align="center">My Skills</h2>

<div class="skillResponsive">
  <!--Div for Skill Bar-->

  <p style="padding-left: 200px;">HTML</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills html">90%</div>
  </div>

  <p style="padding-left: 200px;">CSS</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills css">80%</div>
  </div>

  <p style="padding-left: 200px;">JavaScript</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills js">65%</div>
  </div>

  <p style="padding-left: 200px;">PHP</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills php">60%</div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--End of div for Skill Bar-->
```

So if you could tell me what can I do to get my skill bar to me more responsive when you resize the browser down to tablet and mobile mode. That be great thanks!

A few lines of codes is a plus!

Comment: have a look at here please ; https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_skill_bar.asp

Comment: hi have you tried using media queries?

Comment: just because u have given padding inline.. better give padding on media query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code.. its fully responsive for all device... this will help you. :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.skillResponsive {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
  <h2 align="center">My Skills</h2>

  <div class="skillResponsive">
    <!--Div for Skill Bar-->
  
    <p>HTML</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills html">90%</div>
    </div>
  
    <p>CSS</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills css">80%</div>
    </div>
  
    <p>JavaScript</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills js">65%</div>
    </div>
  
    <p>PHP</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills php">60%</div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  <!--End of div for Skill Bar-->
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That is just what I'm looking for! I used chrome instead for dev mode and it looks so much cleaner on mobile now and as well as desktop! You the man!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.skill-set {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.skills {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}
.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-set">
  <h1>My Skills</h1>
  <p>HTML</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills html">90%</div>
  </div>
  <p>CSS</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills css">80%</div>
  </div>
  <p>JavaScript</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills js">65%</div>
  </div>
  <p>PHP</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills php">60%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i suggest to disable touch simulation (it's the blue hand icon). For some reason in Firefox with this feature enabled, simulation does not work correctly.

Secondly, regarding the code, i always prefer using em/rem for font size (instead of px) and vw/vh for padding/margin/etc (instead of px). It gives relative length instead of absolute. You can find further information below:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Finally, you can find the code as i would use it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.title
{
 padding-left: 10vw;
 font-size: 1rem;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
.skills {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     }
.title {
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     }
}
```

```html
<h2 align="center">My Skills</h2>

  <p class="title">HTML</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills html">90%</div>
  </div>

  <p class="title">CSS</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills css">80%</div>
  </div>

  <p class="title">JavaScript</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills js">65%</div>
  </div>

  <p class="title">PHP</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skills php">60%</div>
  </div>
```